# Find $a$ and $b$ for the function $f(x)= x^3$ if $x \leq 2$ , and $f(x)=ax^2+b$ if $x>2$

Tags: calculus

Function differentiable on all real line is defined with following expressions: $f(x)= x^3$ if $x \leq 2$ , and $f(x)=ax^2+b$ if $x>2$, find $a$ and $b$. There are several answers, such as $a=3, b=-4; a=2, b=0; a=1, b=4$ . The correct answer is the first, and I can not understand why?

Comment: If $f$ is differentiable at $x = 2$, then $\lim_{x \to 2^+} 2ax = \lim_{x \to 2^-} 3x^2 = 3 \cdot 2^2 = 12$.  If $a = 2$ and $b = 0$, then $\lim_{x \to 2^+} 2ax = 2 \cdot 2 \cdot 2 = 8 \neq 12$.  Similarly, if $a = 1$ and $b = 4$, then $\lim_{x \to 2^+} 2ax = 2 \cdot 1 \cdot 2 = 4 \neq 12$.

Answer (score 1):

Due to continuity of $f(x)$ at $x=2$  we have $$\lim_{x\uparrow 2} f(x)= f(2)= \lim_{x\downarrow 2} f(x)$$

i.e $8=8=4a+b$

also from the differentiability of $f$ at $x=2$ we have $12=4a$ so $a=3$ and $b=-4$.

More precisely we have $$\lim_{x\uparrow 2} {f(x)-f(2)\over x-2}=\lim_{x\downarrow 2} {f(x)-f(2)\over x-2}$$

Comment: I know that, but all this choices give the same answer if x approaches 2 from the right, that is why I cannot understand why the right answer is the first one.

Comment: Unless the derivatives match as you approach from both sides, you'll have a 'corner', which will prevent the function from being differentiable at 2, just like how $|x|$ is not differentiable at $x=0$.

Answer (score 1):

Zero order continuity ( for contact) demands

$$  f(x)= f(2)\tag1 $$ as we approach either from right or left.

First order continuity ( for slope) demands

$$  f^{'}(x)= f{'}(2) \tag2 $$ also as we approach from either right or left.

The above two are satisfied for our case when $ a=3, b=-4. $

But there is no second order or curvature continuity, meaning different radii of curvature as we approach from right or left.

$$\lim_{x\uparrow 2} {f^{''} (x)} \ne \lim_{x\downarrow 2} {f^{''} (x)} \tag3 $$